# Can properties be created in Javascript any where?

Tags: javascript, html

If I have an array in JavaScript that starts with `var stars = []` and I create a `star` (code below). I found this code online and am working my way through it so that I can see how it works and to modify it.

Is the `this.stars = stars;` just creating another internal property for this particular class?

```
var stars = []; 
for(var i=0; i<this.stars; i++) {
    stars[i] = new Star(Math.random() * this.width, 
                        Math.random() * this.height, 
                        Math.random() * 3+1,
                       (Math.random() * (this.maxVelocity - this.minVelocity)) 
                        + this.minVelocity);
}

this.stars = stars;  // <-- creating internal property
```

Because I do not see it here in the definition of the class. So I am not certain if it is just created on the spot or if it could be declared in this definition.

---

Code Here:

```
function Starfield() {
    this.fps    = 30;
    this.canvas = null;
    this.width  = 0;
    this.width  = 0;
    this.minVelocity = 15;
    this.maxVelocity = 30;
    this.stars = 9000;
    this.intervalId = 0;
}

//  The main function - initialises the starfield.
Starfield.prototype.initialise = function(div) {
    var self = this; //sets it self to current object

    //  Store the div
    this.containerDiv = div;
    self.width        = window.innerWidth;
    self.height       = window.innerHeight;

    window.onresize = function(event) {
        self.width  = window.innerWidth;
        self.height = window.innerHeight;
        self.canvas.width  = self.width;
        self.canvas.height = self.height;
        self.draw();
    }

    //  Create the canvas.
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    div.appendChild(canvas);
    this.canvas = canvas;
    this.canvas.width  = this.width;
    this.canvas.height = this.height;
};

Starfield.prototype.start = function() {
    //  Create the stars.
    var stars = []; //creates an array that can be used for anything but in this case a star field

    //this.stars is a property in the class that contains a number of the stars
    for(var i=0; i<this.stars; i++) {
        stars[i] = new Star(Math.random() * this.width, 
                            Math.random() * this.height, 
                            Math.random() * 3+1,
                           (Math.random() * (this.maxVelocity - this.minVelocity)) + this.minVelocity);
    }

    this.stars = stars;

    var self = this;
    //  Start the timer.
    this.intervalId = setInterval(function() {
        self.update();
        self.draw();    
    }, 1000 / this.fps);
};

Starfield.prototype.stop = function() {
    clearInterval(this.intervalId);
};

Starfield.prototype.update = function() {
    var dt = 1 / this.fps;

    for(var i=0; i < this.stars.length; i++) {
        var star = this.stars[i];
        star.y += dt * star.velocity;
        //  If the star has moved from the bottom of the screen, spawn it at the top.
        if (star.y > this.height) {
            this.stars[i] = new Star(Math.random() * this.width, 
                                     0, 
                                     Math.random() * 3 + 1, 
                                     (Math.random() * (this.maxVelocity + 60 - this.minVelocity)) + this.minVelocity);
        }
    }
};

Starfield.prototype.draw = function() {
    var ctx = this.canvas.getContext("2d");

    //  Draw the background.
    ctx.fillStyle = '#000000';
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, this.width, this.height);

    //  Draw stars.
    ctx.fillStyle = '#ffffff';
    for(var i=0; i<this.stars.length;i++) {
        var star = this.stars[i];
        ctx.fillRect(star.x, star.y, star.size, star.size);
    }
};

//This is the class for stars -- there are 4 properties that are in this particular class
function Star(x, y, size, velocity) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y; 
    this.size = size;
    this.velocity = velocity;
}
```

Comment: I don't understand your question. No property is created at the line highlighted.

Comment: this.stars = stars; from what I gather this seems to be a new property that is an array of stars. Why can i not declare it above with all of the other properties. I think it would be more readable if it was done that way. this.starfield = [] and then set this.starfield = stars; just my opinion however.

Comment: my point was that it is already defined in `function Starfield() {` as `this.stars = 9000;`. All you're doing in the prototype function is redefining it as an array.

Comment: Just a heads up: Unlike most languages that you may be used to, JavaScript does not have any `classes`.  Even `ES6`, which added the `class` keyword still doesn't really have any classes.

Comment: There referred to as functions correct? And to the other question so in Java script you just make any variable in to an array with redefining it. Could I make it an array of 9000 stars.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, properties can be added at any time in JavaScript. Take a look at this example:

```
function Person(firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}

Person.prototype.getFullName = function() {
    // Notice that I haven't defined this.lastName yet
    return this.firstName + ' ' + this.lastName;
};

var bob = new Person('Bob');
bob.lastName = 'Saget';
console.log(bob.getFullName()); // 'Bob Saget'
```

Comment: The first code block creates a Star object, the second block defines the Starfield object with a stars property. Scroll down for the stars definition. It doesn't have an existing stars property.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Javascript objects are dynamic. They can have new properties added/deleted at any time unless they have been [sealed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/seal) and their properties can be modified at any time unless they have been [frozen](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze).

You probably won't see many sealed or frozen objects in the wild.